# Mybatis @MapperScan wildcard package path usage problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I used `Mybatis-plus` + `Kotlin` + `Springboot`, my configuration is as follows:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.sage.**.mapper", "com.sage.**.mapper.xml")
class MybatisPlusConfig
```

I have a `.xml` file in the following package:

```
src/main/java/com/sage/feature/article/database/mapper/xml/ArticleItemMapper.xml
```

`"com.sage.**.mapper.xml"` configuration didn't work, Only this configuration `"com.sage.**.mapper"` works. (works when the `.xml` file is under the `mapper` package)

What did i do wrong?

Comment: `@MapperScan` searches Java mapper (i.e. .interface), not XML files (which means that the XML mapper must be in the same package as the Java mapper; with proper `namespace`). As you are using mybatis-spring-boot, you don't need `@MapperScan`. Interfaces with `@Mapper` annotation are automatically picked up.

Comment: @ave Yes, maybe I should set the path to the `xml` file, I will try.